# Searchview does not redirect to results page

Tags: android, searchview

I have been trying to redirect my searchview results to another activity upon onquerysubmit but the app just shows me a blank page. I have been trying to debug it but after the onquerysubmit returns false, the debugger just keeps on displaying that the app is running.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".UniversalSearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_universal_search"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"  />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UniversalSearchResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_report_error"
        android:parentActivityName=".UniversalSearchActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>
```

UniversalSearchActivity.java

```
public class UniversalSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RelativeLayout searchSuggestionsLayout;
private ListView searchListView;
private SearchView searchView;
private UniversalSearchAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_universal_search);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_universal_search);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    searchSuggestionsLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_suggestions_container);
    searchListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_suggestions_list);

    adapter = new UniversalSearchAdapter(this, this.getSearch());
    searchListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked an item in the list view!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchItem.expandActionView();

    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this,
                    UniversalSearchResultActivity.class)));
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.placeholder_universal_search));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.requestFocus();

    menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if(query == "") {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please type a hint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        UniversalSearchResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


public ArrayList<UniversalSearch> getSearch() {
    ArrayList<UniversalSearch> searches = new ArrayList<UniversalSearch>();
    UniversalSearch universalSearch;

    for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        universalSearch = new UniversalSearch(names[i], address[i], images[i]);
        searches.add(universalSearch);
    }
    return searches;
}
```

}

UniversalSearchResultActivity.java

```
 public class UniversalSearchResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RelativeLayout searchResultLayout;
private ListView searchResultListView;
private UniversalSearchAdapter universalSearchAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_universal_search_result);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_universal_search_result);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I'm heeeere!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    handleIntent(getIntent());

}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                UniversalSearchResultActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    }
}
```

}

The searchview works fine when the onquerytextchange is used but in the case of onquerytextsubmit, it doesn't. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: try this  <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=CLASS_NAME_OF_SEARCH_ACTIVITY" />

Comment: @Shubham under what activity block should I put that in AndroidManifest?

Comment: under this=> UniversalSearchActivity..
define this in mrta-data android:value=CLASS_NAME_OF_SEARCH_ACTIVITY" for all the activities where you want to add search. I am not sure,. hope this work